# Was Dylan Rhodes a member of the Eye when he frames Thaddeus Bradley?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me, now-you-see-me-2

In Now You See Me 1, Dylan Rhodes framed Thaddeus Bradley, who was the head of the Eye as revealed in Now You See Me 2. Was Dylan working alone to frame Thaddeus? If so then did he lie to the Four Horsemen about being a representative of the Eye?

If Rhodes was working alone and not a member of the Eye then how did he know about the secret carousal entrance?

If he was a member of the Eye, then why did he frame the head of his organization? Also did he not help the Horsemen cheat to get into the Eye by giving them all the plans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a secret organization, The Eye’s structure and leadership might not be known to all but its most trusted members. As a low level Eye member (which Dylan seems to be, based on the sequel), he especially would not be privy to that information.

It appears as if Dylan is handed down assignments from a secret leadership on a regular basis (based again on the sequel). As if he is a field agent grunt. His private vendetta scheme was probably off the books (not sanctioned by leadership). Which is how and why Thaddeus got caught up in it.

Comment: And he helped the Horsemen cheat to get into the Eye, didn't he?

Comment: I wouldn’t call it cheating. It was more of a testing. And, they were able to pass the test. Think of it like a military commanding officer giving his men a battle plan. The men still have to execute it. I can see other Eye applicants going through something similar. In school, a teacher does not give the final exam before the lesson. After all, in the real world, magicians frequently purchase or commission their tricks to be made.